# Assignment operator's return value can be a reference?

Tags: c++

I was surprised to see a bit of syntax in a co-worker's code today.

```
void doSomething(bool& boolRef);

bool ok = true;
doSomething(ok = false);
```

I would think this is an error since the assignment operator in the param, `ok = false`, returns the value of the assigned value, which in this case is false. And since `doSomething` is expecting a reference, my first reaction was "that shouldn't work" since it would seem almost identical to doing `doSomething(false);`

But alas it does work. And reassigning the value of reference inside of `doSomething` works just like you'd expect.

Can someone please explain why this works?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

The canonical assignment operator for a class `Foo` looks like this:

```
class Foo {
  ...

  Foo& operator=(const Foo& other) {
    // make this the same as other
    return *this;
  }
};
```

As you can see, it does return a reference. In this case the object is `ok`, and so it returns a reference to `ok`, which is an lvalue, which is why the call works.

Bool of course is not a class but nonetheless it works the same way, this is *why* the canonical assignment operator is written just like this.

As an aside, I personally don't really care for exploiting this very much and I would probably have written the `doSomething(ok=false)` as two lines, and I suspect many other people would too.

Comment: I think you can remove "probably". Canonical assignment should be written the same way they work for embedded types.

Comment: @Slava I wrote probably only because strictly speaking I'm speculating as to what was on the mind of whoever decided that this would be the canonical form, but I see your point, I'll remove it.

Comment: I'd say as of C++11 this is not canonical anymore. Sometimes the pass-by-value version is better.

Comment: @Brian Not really. Pass-by-value usually means writing swap by hand. There are multiple performance issues with this: implementing move assignment in terms of swap is inefficient, copy construction is often inefficient compared to assignment, etc. The core guidelines specifically suggest passing by `const&`. It can save a very small amount of code duplication, in very specific circumstances; usually code duplication is better avoided with the rule of zero. Hinnant and Meyers have both recommended against it. Etc. If you have a good source arguing its merits I'd be curious to see it.

Answer (score 3):

Assignment returns a reference to the object being assigned to (not the object being assigned from), which in this case is the lvalue `ok`, so the code is also ok, though perhaps not great.

Comment: Err, this answer is a bit vague (yes, what Nicol said).

Comment: @Nicol  Right - fixed it.